# Magento 1: Set attribute default value per website

Tags: attributes, magento-1, websites

Is there any way to set a default attribute value per website in Magento 1?

EDIT:

I mean Attribute Options in Manage Label / Options. There is a possibility to set "Is Default" for some option, but that applies to all websites.

Comment: which attributes?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question with details?